# Unable to change product type field formats in Manage Presentation screen

Tags: ubercart

In one of my Drupal 7 web I'm unable to change the product type field formats in the Content Type - Product - Manage Presentation screen. When changing from 'Visible' to 'Oculto(=Hidden)' I get a screen without overlay or just a white screen, the browser is like keeping loading. However I can change the 'Etiqueta' (=labels) on the same page without problem.
Screenshots of the problem:

After changing, during 2 seconds:
http://www.nauticdirect.es/files/Nauticdirect_problema_campo_product_typ...

After 2 seconds until infinity:
http://www.nauticdirect.es/files/Nauticdirect_problema_campo_product_typ...

I have 3 product types: Product, Anclas and Cabos. The problem occurs with all three types. However it has worked before as I have changed some of these fields one year ago.

I am strugling with this more than a week. I've tried different browers and computers. I have updated all Drupal (7.41 now) and modules to their latest version. Also I have contacted the hosting, they moved to another server and increased available memory size. On this same server I have an almost identical Drupal 7 site where I don't have this problem.

Today I found out the same problems occurrs when adding a condition to a Ubercart shipping quote.

I would be very glad if somebody knows the solution or can give me a hint where to look.

Thanks very much!

Regards,

Henk

Comment: Finally I noted the problem didn't happen if I desable the Overlay module (in the core). Further investigation made me install the jQuery Update module, this solved all problems. It's working now fine also with Overlay enabled.